# RegionInfo.CurrentRegion doesn't correspond to Settings value

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, localization, windows-10

I'm writing a Windows 10 UWP app that needs to bring up a different page depending on what region you're in. I've found that my region always read "US", even if I change the location to China, add a Chinese keyboard, set the language to Chinese, etc. Any idea how to make Windows change the RegionInfo.CurrentRegion?

Comment: After you change the region, did you restart the app?

Comment: yes, a full 15 character yes.